# Authorization Error in Deploying Web app to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio

I am trying to deploy an ASP.Core app to Azure. The app is running inside Visual Studio for me and there is no IIS on my local machine.

I am consistently seeing this error on publish, and it looks like all threads on the web talk about configuring IIS. But since I am not even running IIS, I cannot figure out what to set. Has anyone else figured this out specifically from VS Studio->Azure (IIS local in VS only)?

This is the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer (".scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct username and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permission to access the site.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)
Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
Error details:
Connected to the remote computer (".scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct username and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permission to access the site.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.

thanks.

I have tried changing properties on the Azure web app, and tried searching online - but everything mentions IIS configuration.

Comment: Is your Azure Subscription active ?

Comment: Also, do you have the required access for deployment? Contributor atleast?